CA Unknown with PHP API Call
I am trying to get a php script to work on an internal IIS server.  I have php working on this server with several scripts without any problems.  These scripts are making calls to other internal servers in the enterprise but a new script I am working on makes an API call out to an external website for ServiceNow.  I am very limited in php skills, and I did try to search as best I could to come across a post that was similar to my problem but just couldn't find one.  I am running php on windows with v7.3.11.
The php script is not completing and a wireshark capture shows syn, client hello, ack, and then fatal with Unknown CA.  This is a public website that has a 3rd party well known issuer.  From this windows server I can browse to the url with no cert issue.
If I understand correctly php may use the default windows certificate store.  I did try to import the cert into windows store but that didn't seem to help.  I also tried to update the php.ini to point to specific curl.cainfo but that did not seem to help either.  Maybe I am missing something in either of those attempts?
I have reached my limit on where to go next for php help.  If I can browse to this url without cert issue from a web browser on this server but the php api call gets unknown CA what else could be the issue?
Many thanks in advance!

Try posting the question on serverfault.com
